# php-fpm not working several days,return 'No input file specified'

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, php-cgi

My server running ubuntu 64bit, nginx, php-fpm.
 Everything is working well. But several days after. The browser display 'No input file specified'.
After I restart php-fpm. Everything run well again.
But this situation occur again and again.
So I must restart the php-fpm several days.
Anyone know what's the problem?

nginx -V output

```
sshadmin@ubuntu:~$ nginx -V
nginx: nginx version: nginx/0.9.7
nginx: built by gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 
nginx: TLS SNI support enabled
nginx: configure arguments: --user=www --group=www --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_gzip_static_module
```

Answer (score 1):

Its likely to be https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Nginx#Error:_No_input_file_specified
but you need to provide some more information for us to be able to narrow it down further.

To start off providing the output from 'nginx -V output' should rule out my first suggestion

Comment: The problem is not the configuration and permission. It run well for several days.

Comment: Checked all the relevant logs?  Checked file system availability?